# Calling a controller function through a button

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm having some troubles using Symfony 2 and requests.
I am reading some docs but it just confuses me.
Can you clear this easy point for me ? Thanks.

I am creating a website with some articles that a user can add to his favorites.
All the entities are ok, the mapping and the base too. I just have front problems.

I want a button on the article page which calls a function in my controller (which calls the right repository methods) and don't refresh the page (that's why I can't use PHP only).
I am thinking about changing the color of the button if the call works.

What do you use for that ? I don't need the result, I know how stackoverflow works, just foo/bar steps or name methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know something like black letters are equal to buffalo.

Comment: What do you mean ? I'm not native english and can't understand this hindi citation. I did wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to use here is jQuery.

U need a route in the controller to refer to:

```
/**
 * @Route("/do_something", name="your_action_route")
 */
public function doSomethingAction(Request $request) {
```

And then you can ad js script in your twig template:

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
     $.ajax('{{ path('your_action_route') }}', {
                    data: { 
                            // you can pass some parameters to the controller here
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                            // change button color
                    },
                    error: function() {
                            // show alert or something
                    }
                });
    return false; // this stops normal button behaviour from executing;

});
```

This way, whenever you click a button on your site, the ajax request will execute your action in controller.

Comment: That's perfect and clear. Thanks for your help. That's really kind.